# Access test database from third party client in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having this problem: In my test, I have a HTTP client which would send a request to my server to create a record (in test database). If I start the server normally like this: `mix phx.server` it would create a record in the development database. So I've tried `MIX_ENV=test iex -S mix phx.server` to start the server in the test environment, then I run the test with this command `MIX_ENV=test iex -S mix test`. But I keep getting the error message:

** (Mix) The database for MyApp.Repo couldn't be dropped: ERROR 55006 (object_in_use): database "my_app_test" is being accessed by other users

There are 10 other sessions using the database.

I've tried to search but seems like there are no similar problems, any help would be very appreciated. Thanks, guys.

Comment: I don't think you need to run `MIX_ENV=test iex -S mix phx.server` before running your tests. Did you try without it already?

Comment: In your config/test.exs file, set server: true under the endpoint's configuration. This will start the server when you run mix test. It is not enabled by default.